# How to template If-Else structures in data-bound views?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I constantly find myself using this idiom in KO-based HTML templates:

```html
<!-- ko if: isEdit -->
<td><input type="text" name="email" data-bind="value: email" /></td>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: isEdit -->
<td data-bind="text: email"></td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do conditionals in KO, or is there a better *approach* than just using traditional if-else constructs?

Also, I would just like to point out that some versions of Internet Explorer (IE 8/9) don't parse the above example correctly. Please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613668/knockout-virtual-elements-between-tr-tags-in-ie-browsers) for more information. The quick summary is, don't use comments (virtual bindings) inside table tags to support IE. Use the `tbody` instead:

```html
<tbody data-bind="if: display"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: Anyone looking at this may wish to track https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/962

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are a couple different ways that you can handle this type of code.

- with an if/ifnot combination like you are now.  This works fine and is not terribly verbose.
- Michael Best's switch/case binding (https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case) is quite flexible and can let you easily handle this and more complicated ones (more states than true/false).
- Another option is to use dynamic templates.  You would bind an area to one or more templates with the template name being used based on an observable.  Here is a post that I wrote on this topic a while back: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-dynamically-changing.html.  In  your scenario, it might look like:

```html
<td data-bind="template: $root.getCellTemplate"></td>

<script id="cellEditTmpl" type="text/html">
    <input type="text" name="email" data-bind="value: email" />
</script>

<script id="cellTmpl" type="text/html">
    <span data-bind="text: email"></span>
</script>
```

The `getCellTemplate` function could live wherever, but would be given the item ($data) as the first argument and would return the name of the template to use.

Comment: strange, my HTML won't show up.  Also just noticed that Michael gave pretty much the same answer.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive list of options. I guess my original code style works for simple cases. I'll check out the other options when the need arises.

Comment: is there a way to customize the template even more, such as "template: data, proppertyName: 'email'" and in the template data-bind="text: $data[propertyName]".

Comment: @OnurTOPAL - yes as long as you have a variable `propertyName`, you can dynamically determine the template name.

Answer (score 44):

One approach is to use named templates (which can support passing arguments):

```
<!-- ko template: isEdit() ? 'emailEdit' : 'emailDisplay' --><!-- /ko -->
<script id="emailEdit" type="text/html">
    <td><input type="text" name="email" data-bind="value: email" /></td>
</script>
<script id="emailDisplay" type="text/html">
    <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
</script>
```

Another option is use my [switch/case plugin](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case), which would work like this:

```
<!-- ko switch -->
    <!-- ko case: isEdit -->
        <td><input type="text" name="email" data-bind="value: email" /></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko case: $else -->
        <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep the switch/case plugin in mind for when the need arises.

Comment: Nice plugin you got there! Will use this one for sure.

Comment: Named templates works great, and it supports if elseif elseif else type scenarios by nesting the terniary operator.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid recalculation of knockout binding when using combination of if: / ifnot: you can use them in conjunction with 'with:' construction

```
    <!-- ko with: $data.DoSomePerformanceCriticalWork($data.SomeParameter()) -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.Condition() -->
           ... some markup ...
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: $data.Condition() -->
           ... some markup ...
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now also the [`knockout-else`](https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-else) binding/plugin (that I wrote to address this issue).

Comment: is it possible to use knockout-else with KSB? If yes then how to use that? your answer will be appreciate. Thanks for make libraries like KSB.