# Knockout Virtual Elements between TR tags in IE browsers

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
...
</tr>
<!-- ko if: eLocBound() == 'true' -->
<tr>
    <td>Select Locations <span class="required_star">*</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
<tr>
...
```

This displays correctly in Chrome/Firefox/Safari. However, when I load the page in IE 9, the following error occurs:

`Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko if: eLocBound() == 'true'`

When I check the HTML output in IE's developer window, I discover that IE is actually nesting the `<!-- ko if -->` comment tag *inside* the previous TR tag instead of in between the TR tags, thus Knockout is unable to find the matching `<!-- /ko -->` tag. I've linked to a screenshot of the problem here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wDPU.jpg

Conversely, if I change the code to this:

```
<tr data-bind="visible: eLocBound() == 'true'">
    <td>Select Locations <span class="required_star">*</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
```

Then everything works fine. I would just like to know if anyone has encountered this problem with virtual elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with Internet Explorer that Knockout can't really compensate for.  In your case, a good workaround is to use a `tbody` tag around your row.   A table can include multiple `tbody` tags.  So, your code would look like:

```
 ...
</tr>
<tbody data-bind="if: eLocBound() == 'true'">
<tr>
    <td>Select Locations <span class="required_star">*</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tr>
...
```

Comment: I thought so... thanks for confirming the this case I have to take note of for IE. I actually went with the virtual element because the TR tag was already wrapped in a TBODY tag that had a separate visibility logic attached to it. Will just use this for future cases.