# Removing metadata-generated table rows in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, mvvm, knockout.js

For my first stackoverflow question. Please pardon my general lack of understanding. I'm working on that.

I am auto-generating a table based on user identified dates that have different record values for each day provided. I am referencing a .JSON metagen/metadata file that defines the rows and columns, yet I cannot seem to find a way to filter out the results that are being passed as empty objects. I want to delete the rows without results. I believe I need to create a  or reference a viewmodel function inside a binding, but everything I have tried so far has failed.

I have a bindings file that reads in the data and calculates the fields as they are queried based on the record names. The records are then created with knockout foreach statements and the values are taken from a Subgrid() function found in my bindings file. The data is read in as number format.

The View

```
 <!-- ko foreach: $data.cols -->
                        <th data-bind="text:$data.label === undefined ? $data.value:$data.label"></th>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- ko foreach: $data.rows -->
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text:$data.label === undefined ? $data.value:$data.label"></td>
                        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.cols -->
                            <td data-class="subgridRow"></td>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
```

The Viewmodel

```
/*global define,sandbox */
define([
    'scalejs.sandbox!subgrid',
], function (
    sandbox
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (node) {
        var observable = sandbox.mvvm.observable,
            merge = sandbox.object.merge,
            text = observable(node.text);
            sandbox.flag.invoke('loadUwf');                 
        return merge(node, {
            text: text }
```

The return portion of the bindings file.

```
//remove values for missing LoB records and return the value
loop1:  for (var obj in exdata){  
                for (var key in exdata[obj]){
                        if (exdata[obj][key]=== parentValue || ctx.$parent.value === "TOTAL"){
                                if( !text ){text = 0;}
                                if (ctx.$parent.value === "TOTAL"){
                        return {text: recalc.total.toFixed(round) + ' ' + unit,}}
                        else{return {text: recalc.val.toFixed(round) + ' ' + unit,}
                        break loop1;}
```

Comment: Sorry if I don't fully understand your question but from what I can understand what you are looking for is "Computed Observable". you can bind the UI to a computed observable (an array that filters out null values).

Comment: Please read this to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve As it stated, it's impossibleto imagine how your vm looks like and what you need to do.

Comment: Also be very, very careful with virtual ko tags inside tables, especially in IE, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613668/knockout-virtual-elements-between-tr-tags-in-ie-browsers) for potential gotcha's.