# Container less If Else Condition in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

1. How can I write container less if else and nested if else conditions
2. Please also explain how does it work as normal (if condition) in KO.

Comment: Have you checked the official KO documentation? The basics are there: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: i have a condition like :   
 '<!-- ko if: getApplicationType() != "soft" -->
 alert("Hardware");
    <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if: getApplicationType() == "soft" -->
 alert("Software");
    <!-- /ko -->'    can you make it if else condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout JS If-Else bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553999/knockout-js-if-else-bindings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered before: [How to template If-Else structures in data-bound views?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553999/1287183)

But, for a true if/else binding, you can check out this Github issue: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/962