# How to handle if/else statement in knockout container less form?

Tags: knockout.js

Is this possible to have if-else statement when using knockout container less statements?  I mean Something like:

```
<!-- ko else -->
```

Comment: there is no ko else. but you can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553999/knockout-js-if-else-bindings

Comment: Checkout this blog : https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-use-if-else-in-knockout-js-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As mentioned, there isn't an `else`, but it's common to combine `ko if` and `ko ifnot` using the same flag.

```
<!-- ko if: myFlag -->
    ...some stuff for the true case
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: myFlag -->
    ...some stuff for the else (false) case
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: check the link for knockout and Magento 2, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/set-if-else-knockout-js-magento-2/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no `<!-- ko else -->`.  you will need to use two `<!-- ko if: something-is-true -->` statements or use templates to achieve the same thing as @huocp mentioned with the link to [Knockout JS If-Else bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553999/29467)

Answer (score 1):

One solution already mentioned in above answers using ifnot.But you can use same this way

```
<!-- ko if: myFlag -->
    ..if statement work here
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: !(myFlag) -->
    ..else statement work here
<!-- /ko -->
```